# Constant used to determine the minimum samples in Compressed Sensing

Tags: computer-vision, compressive-sensing

A key result in compressive sensing states that, with high probability on the random
draw of an $\ m × N$ Gaussian or Bernoulli matrix $\ A$, all $\ s$-sparse vectors $\ x$ can be reconstructed from $\ y = Ax$ using a variety of algorithms provided

$\ m ≥ Cs\ln(N/s)$,

where $\ C > 0$ is a universal constant (independent of $\ s, m,$  and $\ N$). This bound is in fact optimal.

In practical terms, how does one interpret/find $\ C$?

source: http://www.cis.pku.edu.cn/faculty/vision/zlin/A%20Mathematical%20Introduction%20to%20Compressive%20Sensing.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constant C is usually left unspecified as it can be very hard to calculate.  It is independent of the signal dimension, and results in Compressed Sensing are generally only concerned with big-O results, so it falls out when we say something like $m = \mathcal{O}(s \ln{(N/s)})$.  The important part in this statement is the strong dependence on the sparsity level, and that the signal dimension $N$ only logarithmically affects the number of measurements.

To give an example of where such a constant would come from:  Let $V_d$ be the volume of the unit $\ell_2$ ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Some simple cases are that $V_2 = \pi r^2$ and $V_3 = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$.  Note that both of these results are of the form $V_d = C r^d$, and this pattern generalizes for finite $d$.  In CS, it is $r^d$ that we are interested in, as it captures the dependence on the signal dimension.

So $C$ will vary depending on the algorithm as different inequalities may be used in the proofs.  I don't know of any publications that specifically calculate C.

Comment: thanks, this answer is really clear to me. This means that given a missing data problem (e.g. matrix completion) the best I can do if asked "do you have enough samples?" is to give a ballpark Yes or No. Then actually test it empirically (assuming suitable incoherence).

Answer (score 1):

C depends , among other things, on the reconstruction algorithm.

Comment: can you explain your answer with more details?

Comment: @Igor Perhaps I could have a brief example? Do you mean, for instance, that using a hard/soft thresholding algorithm vs orthogonal matching pursuit would result in different C values? What other things might there be to influence C? Can you point me to any references where they specifically address what things have an effect on C? Thanks!